# R Random Forrest - Use tthe mean of a input variable of all values as varibales

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a theoretical question.
I have a dataframe with a categorical response with levels: 1,2,3,4

And I have one feature with lists for for each response row.
So the rows looks like this:

```
Y_1 = 1 - X_1 =  list(0.56,0.67,0.34...)
...
Y_N = 3 - X_N =  list(0.12,0.69,0.99...)
```

The question is: Is it equal to use the mean or all values (so each value is its own variable) of the the input?